# Easy to do experiments that clearly show outstanding properties of graphene

Tags: experimental-physics, home-experiment, graphene

By chance we received for free some monolayer graphene sheets (20 cm x 20 cm) and mixed coper-graphene wires at our University. I would like to prepare some very easy to do experiments for the chemistry students that show the awesome properties of graphene, and which could be carried out with very simple lab equipment or even home experiments, any ideas or references?

Answer (score 1):

Electric **resistance is low in a layer of graphene** due to delocalized electrons of the [benzene rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aromaticity). Your chemistry students propably know about the visualisation with three double/single-bonds and wondered about that.

This simple experiment with a multimeter also demonstrates [graphene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphene) as an electric insulator inbetween two layers. Concluding the fact that there are no chemical bonds between two layers of graphene. These layers may be shifted, acting against van-der-Waals force.